# Siema slider intialization in mounted fires before v-for elements are loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vue-component, siema

I'm trying to create a siema slider displaying elements in an array using v-for. I initialize the siema slider in the Mounted method, however, when I try to do that, I get the error message `TypeError: this.innerElements[r] is undefined`. When I hardcode the slides, everything perfectly. It seems like the page tries to initialize the slider before the v-for elements are loaded, which should not be the case.

For testing purposes, I moved the code in `initSiema()` from mounted to a seperate method. I already tried calling the method from `beforeUpdate()`, from an if-clause with the condition that there are elements of class slide, and also using `nextTick`.

Is there any way to call the method after the content has properly loaded? Or am I missing something here?

```
let template =
        '<div class="slider-wrapper" @mouseover="hovered = true" @mouseleave="hovered = false">' +
            '<div class="slider-home">' +
                '<div v-for="slide in sliderItems" :key="slide.id" class="slide" :style="slide.Image ? {backgroundImage: getUrl(slide.Image)}: \' \'">' +
                    ------- Here I display the slides -------
                '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="controller">' +
                '<span class="btn prev"></span>' +
                '<span class="btn next"></span>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    Vue.component('slider-home', {
        data: function () {
            return {
                hovered: false,
                sliderItems: null,
                apiUrl: appConstants.apiUrl
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getUrl(image) {
                const url = image.formats.large ? image.formats.large.url : image.url;
                return  'url(' + this.apiUrl + url + ')';
            },
            initSiema() {
                const sliderHome = document.querySelector('.slider-home');
                const homeSlider = new Siema(
                    {
                        selector: sliderHome,
                        duration: 800,
                        loop: true
                    }
                );
                const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
                const next = document.querySelector('.next');
                prev.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    homeSlider.prev()
                });
                next.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    homeSlider.next()
                });
                setInterval(() => {
                    if (!this.hovered) {
                        homeSlider.next()
                    }
                }, 4500);
            }
        },
        beforeCreate: function(){
            const _self = this;
            axios.get(appConstants.apiUrl + '/sliders').then( function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                _self.sliderItems = response.data;
            });
        },
        mounted: function (){

            this.initSiema());

        }
        template: template
    });

    new Vue({
        el: '#slider-home',
        template: '<div><slider-home></slider-home></div>',
    });
```

Comment: If someone encounters the same problem: I managed to solve it by setting a timeout to initializing siema using setTimeout :)